# Random Number In A Range

Tags: java, ios, random

I have an app I am writing for iOS and Android. On startup I am trying to get a random number between 1 and 6.

iOS (Objective-C):

```
int random = rand() % (6 - 1) + 1;
```

Android (Java):

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.nextInt(6)+1;
```

In both cases they return 3 every time.

From other questions I have read, people are having the same issue because they are looping through randoms and keep reinstantiating the Random object. But I just want one random number, so I am only instantiating it once.

So, how can I get either of these pieces of code to get a number 1-6 instead of just 3?

Comment: Random random = new Random(long seed); may it help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: @Nambari In [theory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29) the parameter-less constructor should seed the generator with "something reasonably unique".

Comment: @MichałKosmulski: Agree, but when OP want something different for each OS, it need to be seeded generator than default. Something like David answer.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas everyone, Martijn answered both clearly.

Comment: For Java really consider using the `SecureRandom` class. For Objective-C consider using arc4random and arc4random_uniform. These are cryptographic quality and easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Objective-C part, I can tell you that you have to seed the random, like this:

```
srand(time(0)); // seed it using the current time
```

And for the Java part, the `new Random()` constructor automatically seeds it in the default JVM for desktop applications, [but not on Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29). On Android, it uses a default seed value.

```
Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering both, I tried System.currentTimeMillis for a seed on Android. It didn't seem random, but I am sure it was I was just in too big of a hurry to test it thoroughly. Thanks again.

Comment: `srand()` is a very poor choice, consider arc4random().

Comment: @Zaph: Thanks for the information. I didn't know that function. But for now, with my current project, I will stick with rand(), because I want to be able to define the seed.

Comment: If you need repeatability for any reason, say testing, then srand() is a good choice. Otherwise arc4random() and it's like are better choices,they approach truly random numbers. Seeding with the time is a poor choice, for secure uses.

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, you could alternately use the recommended `arc4random()` function that does not need to be seeded. You would use it like this:

```
int random = (arc4random() % 5) + 1;
```

A huge benefit of this function over `rand()` is that is has twice the range of `rand()`, thus allowing for "more random" numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use `arc4random_uniform` if possible, it is available in iOS 4.3 and above. It eliminates bias that is usually introduced by the mod operator.

```
+ (u_int32_t)randomInRangeLo:(u_int32_t)loBound toHi:(u_int32_t)hiBound {
    int32_t   range = hiBound - loBound + 1;
    return loBound + arc4random_uniform(range);
}
```

Note that no seeding is necessary and it produces cryptographic quality random numbers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the information. Security and complete randomness aren't major issues for what I am doing, but this is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Random on Android, but in other cases, you probably want to seed the Random instance with something reasonably unique, like the system time.

`Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: Cool, I actually tried that, but forgot to mention in my post. It almost seemed to go in order 1,2,3,4,5,6 every time so I didn't think it was working, but I will check again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Java part and it works OK for me, but you can try to instantiate Random using time as a seed:

```
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
    Random random = new Random(d.getTime());
    int num = random.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: This is probably similar to what I tried, System.currentTimeMillis. Thanks for the answer.